# Python raising Value Error when adding column names to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I've been writing some code to parse data into a DataFrame and perform calculations upon it. It had been working so far but after adding column names, the code freaks out and raises a ValueError:

`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (10, 1), indices imply (10, 10)`

Here is the relevant code block:

```
holds_names = ["Left_Mean", "Left_SD", "Left_Skew", "Left_Kurt", "Right_Mean", "Right_SD", "Right_Skew", "Right_Kurt", "Mean_Dif", "PD"]


stat = 1

holdl = pd.to_numeric(df1[df1[3] == 'L'][4], errors='coerce')
holdl = holdl.dropna()
holdl = np.array(holdl[holdl < 1000])

LM = np.mean(holdl)
LSD = np.std(holdl)
LSK = scipy.stats.skew(holdl)
LK = scipy.stats.kurtosis(holdl)

holdr = pd.to_numeric(df1[df1[3] == 'R'][4], errors='coerce')
holdr = holdr.dropna()
holdl = np.array(holdr[holdr < 1000])

RM = np.mean(holdr)
RSD = np.std(holdr)
RSK = scipy.stats.skew(holdr)
RK = scipy.stats.kurtosis(holdr)

MD_1 = abs(LM - RM)

holds_data = [LM, LSD, LSK, LK, RM, RSD, RSK, RK, MD_1, stat]

hdf = pd.DataFrame(holds_data, columns=holds_names)
holds = holds.append(hdf)
```

I am really quite confused because when I remove the columns parameter from hdf, it works fine (albeit in one long column with no column names).

How do I go about fixing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

does changing this line of code solve?

```
holds_data = [LM, LSD, LSK, LK, RM, RSD, RSK, RK, MD_1, stat]
```

to:

```
holds_data = [[LM, LSD, LSK, LK, RM, RSD, RSK, RK, MD_1, stat]]
```

OR

```
hdf = pd.DataFrame(holds_data, columns=holds_names)
```

TO

```
hdf = pd.DataFrame([holds_data], columns=holds_names)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I had a question though, why does this work?

Comment: Not sure of a more technical explanation but adding brackets [ ] is pandas way of knowing that they are rows. Please accept as solution! thank you!